# Official Microsoft Metro Themes for Silverlight and WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, themes

Are there any official Microsoft metro themes for Silverlight and WPF?

I was assuming there has, because they specifically said it in their [Windows 8 User Experience Guidelines](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/A/C0AEF0CC-B969-406D-989A-4CDAFDBB3F3C/Win8_UXG_RTM.pdf)

> ## Win as one
>
> Work with other apps, devices, and the system to complete scenarios for people, like picking
>   content from one app and sharing it with another. Take advantage of what people already know,
>   like standard touch gestures and charms, to provide a sense of familiarity, control, and
>   confidence.
>
> - Fit into the UI model.
> - Reduce redundancy in your UI.
> - Work with other apps to complete scenarios by participating in app contracts.
> - **Use our tools and templates to promote consistency.**
>
> Following these five Metro style design principles will help you make the best choices when
>   designing your app.

I was trying to search it but I only found some resource not from Microsoft.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any official ones (at least my google skills haven't allowed me to find one despite regular searches). But I've used this before and it is excellent:
http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

If you follow the link there are screenshots and instructions on how to use (you'll be up and running in no time).

Comment: Indeed MahApps is promising. But the only drawback is they don't include some vital controls like DataGrid and DateTimePicker, which you need in almost every LOB application.
DataGrid and D.P. has long become a part of WPF.

Comment: While this tool or library may help answer the question, [you must at least explain why it does so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).